# Dual-Color Text

Tags: html, css, text

is there a way to achieve the effect in the sample below,
without duplicating content, just using html and css?

So you basically have a Text that is color1 and background1 on one side and color2 plus background2 on the other side?

Example Code to copy:

```html
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: black; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;display: inline-block;">
    <p style="width: 200%; color: white">
    I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. However, to get this, i need duplicated content. Is there a css way to do the same effect without duplicated content? I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. However, to get this, i need duplicated content. Is there a css way to do the same effect without duplicated content?
    </p>
    </div><div style="width: 50%; background-color: white; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;display: inline-block;">
    <p style="width: 200%; color: black; transform: translateX(-50%)">
    I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. However, to get this, i need duplicated content. Is there a css way to do the same effect without duplicated content? I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. However, to get this, i need duplicated content. Is there a css way to do the same effect without duplicated content?
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use JavaScript for this. There are some nice css solutions answers yet. Sadly none of them seems to work in IE. So i might consider a fallback for IE. I did not ask for this in the beginning, so I'll accept the solution that is compatible to most commonly used browsers tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `background-clip:text` to color the text with a gradient and you can easily have any combination of color:

```css
#main {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, #fff 50%);
}

#main>p {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 50%, #fff 50%);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. No duplicated content was needed for this effect. It's created by using blending effects. I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. No duplicated
    content was needed for this effect. It's created by using blending effects.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by setting the [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) CSS property to the value `difference`. (I've also given an example of how you can create this background image without `transform`.)

As an added bonus, this also makes text selection work properly. :)

```css
#main {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
}

#main > p {
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<p>I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. No duplicated content was needed for this effect. It's created by using blending effects. I am multicolor text. Multicolor text i am. This really does feel great. No duplicated content was needed for this effect. It's created by using blending effects.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Weirdly, it almost looks like the text is bolded. If i swap the color to something like `#f00` it goes away, so it might be an optical illusion.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas "an optical illusion..." It is not an illusion.  `mix-blend-mode` and `filter` force browser to do not use ClearType (or similar technique) but to fallback to grayscale anti-aliasing.  Grayscale AA looks bolder as a rule.